# JS/PHP/HTML problem with onload

Tags: php, javascript, html

index.php

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="lol.js.php"></script>
</head>


<?php
    //grab product id's who need to be showed
    $pids = '1,2,3';
?>

<body onload="update_timers();">
```

lol.js.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function update_timers()
{
    alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but this isn't poping up the alert window. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
```

from the JS file.

The JavaScript error console in your browser should show these tags as syntax errors.

Also, as @Jared points out, you should send a content type header:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the lol.js.php page also need to contain a header directive for the content-type? (Not sure if this is mandatory or not)

Comment: You mean, adding header(..something..) to the JS file? Not working without it by the way...

Comment: @Tool yup. (It'll work in some browsers, and won't in others.)

Comment: What about the argument of the header? Location or Content-type? A bit help if possible :). <?php header('what here?'); ?>

Comment: @Tool - the header directive to use is in Pekka's answer.

Comment: Did that. Still not poping the alert box. I guess it just doesn't work in Mozilla.

Comment: @Tool are you 100% sure the script file is getting loaded? What does the error console say? It should contain some messages.